# Get information about inbuilt storage - Samsung Smart TV App

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am using Samsung smart TV SDK 5.1 to develop a simple application based on HTML5 and Javascript. I am using the file API to read/write files on the inbuilt storage.

I want to know- Is there is any way I can get the total internal storage and the remaining/free space of the internal storage.

PS: I am using the "2014_Smart_B2B_Emulator_2_0" for development.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the response that I got in the forum-**

"there is no such api available by which you can get the total internal storage and the remaining/free space of the internal storage".

URL-
 http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/df3455b529adf7c4?forumID=8838b9f4511e7ec0

---

**Here is the response from the Samsung Support:**

Following are the APIs that you can use:
GetFreeSize()
GetUsedSize()

Details can be found at following location:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/B2B/Guide/ref50002/file_api_getfreesize.html
http://www.samsungdforum.com/B2B/Guide/ref50002/file_api_GetUsedSize.html